# Remove upper array elements that are out of range in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, conditional-statements

I have a simple question related to arrays in php.
Here is the problem.

I have an array like this

```
$week_array =   array(
                    '2013-08-18',
                    '2013-08-11',
                    '2013-08-04',
                    '2013-07-28',
                    '2013-07-21',
                );
```

And i am retrieving these records

```
$records   =   array(
                    array(  '2013-08-06'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-05'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-04'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-03'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-03'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-02'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-02'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-01'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-01'   ),
                    array(  '2013-07-31'  ),
                    array(  '2013-07-31'  ),
                    array(  '2013-07-30'  ),
                );
```

Here is my code

```
$week_counter = 0;              
foreach($records as $row){
    if($row['date'] < $week_array[$week_counter] && $row['date'] >=$week_array[$week_counter+1]){
        echo 'workig';
        echo '<br>';
        $week_counter++;
    }
}
```

On the base of condition i want to display summery(which i ommitted here). but it displays nothing because condition never meets. When the data is being fetched and range is properly meet the summery is displayed.
Now how can i move pointer to the exact range where from which my records should be matched. in simple words i want to remove some elements of array so that new array is formed like this.

```
$week_array    =   array(
                    '2013-08-11',
                    '2013-08-04',
                    '2013-07-28',
                    '2013-07-21',
                );
```

Because the starting date is `2013-08-06` which is coming between first and second values therefore i want to move pointer to the first index instead of remaining at 0 or i want to slice array. How can i do that?

The other thing is that i cant change the condition i provided because it is already displaying summery properly.

EDITS

```
$records   =   array(
                    array(  '2013-08-12'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-09'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-06'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-06'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-05'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-04'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-03'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-03'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-02'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-02'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-01'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-01'   ),
                    array(  '2013-07-31'  ),
                    array(  '2013-07-31'  ),
                    array(  '2013-07-30'  ),
```

In this array you can see there records coming in first and second ranges.

Comment: Your condition will never work because a date cannot be earlier and also equals or later than another ... So please make clear what the expected result should be regarding which variables!

Comment: Are you really comparing the raw strings? This can't work. How should PHP know which string is "bigger"? You must convert them into numbers or write your own comparison.

Comment: @Chris: The raw string comparison will work with this explicit format. Try it yourself. :)

Comment: sorry i have updated the question

Comment: Please show me a date where this condition: `$row['date'] < $week_array[$week_counter] && $row['date'] >=$week_array[$week_counter]` will return true!

Comment: @raheelshan: i think you do not understand me. You said, that you cannot change the condition because it is generating a correct summary. But how is this possible when no date ever you pass to that condition will let the condition return true. No date can be before, equals and later than another date. So you need to define a range. But you only compare two dates with each other. How is there a defined range?

Comment: @TobiasKun run this code and see `if('2013-08-06' < '2013-08-18' AND '2013-08-12' >= '2013-08-11'){
    echo 'working';
}` in http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: @raheelshan: Well mate that will work. But your condition is not build like this. Your condition will be something like this: `if('2013-08-06' < '2013-08-18' AND '2013-08-06' >= '2013-08-18'){ echo 'working'; }`. You use `$row['date']` and `$week_array[$week_counter]` twice and they will not change in this check.

Comment: sorry i am updating one thing missing. I have added +1 in condition. Can you help now?

Comment: And did you have this `$week_counter+` in your real code?

Comment: yes. but while editing it was removed

Comment: If you use the first `$record` array your condition will never return true because there is no date that is later then '2013-08-11'.

Comment: that's what i have been telling. And if you haven't read the question properly please read it. i need to eliminate upper indexes of week array so everything work properly

Comment: @raheelshan: Wow mate. If you want to get proper answers than add the correct code to you question. Thx for the slap in the face though. I'm out ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i found it working like this

```
$week_array    =   array(
                '2013-08-18',
                '2013-08-11',
                '2013-08-04',
                '2013-07-28',
                '2013-07-21',
            );

$records   =   array(
                    array(  '2013-08-06'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-06'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-05'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-04'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-03'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-03'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-02'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-02'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-01'   ),
                    array(  '2013-08-01'   ),
                    array(  '2013-07-31'  ),
                    array(  '2013-07-31'  ),
                    array(  '2013-07-30'  ),
                );
$week_counter = 0;  

if(count($week_array) > 0){
    $counter    =   0;
    foreach($week_array as $sunday){
        if($calls[0] > $sunday){
            $week_array =   array_slice($week_array, $counter );
            break;  
        }
        $counter++;
    }
}   

foreach($records as $row){
    if($row['date'] < $week_array[$week_counter] && $row['date'] >=$week_array[$week_counter+1]){
        echo 'workig';
        echo '<br>';
        $week_counter++;
    }
}
```

That's working exactly what i wanted. As the newly generated week array before loop is like this

```
$week_array    =   array(
                '2013-08-11',
                '2013-08-04',
                '2013-07-28',
                '2013-07-21',
            );
```

Comment: @TobiasKun sorry for the trouble i made i found an answer

Comment: If this solved your issue you should click on the check to mark your questions as answered.